# Evolution equation in renormalization group for infinitely-many variables

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, $L \gg 1$ and define the torus $\mathbb{T} = \varepsilon \mathbb{Z}^{d}/L\mathbb{Z}^{d}$. Let $K$ be a smooth, strictly decreasing function. To make things easier, consider an explicit example of a regularized propagator:
$$C_{\Lambda,\Lambda_{0}}(x,y) = \int_{\mathbb{T}^{*}}dp \frac{1}{D_{\varepsilon}(p)+m^{2}}e^{i\langle p,x-y\rangle}\bigg{[}K\bigg{(}\frac{p^{2}}{\Lambda_{0}^{2}}\bigg{)}-K\bigg{(}\frac{p^{2}}{\Lambda^{2}}\bigg{)}\bigg{]}$$
where:
$$D_{\varepsilon}(p) = \frac{2}{\varepsilon^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{d}(1-\cos(\varepsilon p_{k}))$$
and $\Lambda \in [\Lambda_{1},\Lambda_{0}]$, with $0 < \Lambda_{1} < \Lambda_{0}$.

Because $x,y \in \mathbb{T}$, we are actually in a lattice and $C_{\Lambda,\Lambda_{0}}(x,y)$ is just a matrix. Define:
$$e^{\mathcal{G}(\phi,C_{\Lambda,\Lambda_{0}},-\lambda V)} = \int d\mu_{C_{\Lambda,\Lambda_{0}}}(\chi)e^{-\lambda V(\chi+\phi)}. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Because it is given in terms of a Gaussian convolution, $\mathcal{G}$ formally satisfies:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{G}}{\partial \Lambda} = \Delta_{\dot{C}_{\Lambda,\Lambda_{0}}}\mathcal{G}+\frac{1}{2}\langle \nabla \mathcal{G}, \dot{C}_{\Lambda,\Lambda_{0}}\nabla \mathcal{G}\rangle \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where the dot in $\dot{C}_{\Lambda,\Lambda_{0}}$ means derivative with respect to $\Lambda$. This is the evolution equation for the renormalization group dynamics.

Now it comes my question. The above scenario works for both bosons and fermions. As it is, the derivatives are just regular partial derivatives. For bosons, taking $\varepsilon \to 0$ and $L \to \infty$ lead to a continuum and infinite volume limits, and the derivatives become functional derivatives in the sense of distributions. I want to know what happens for fermions. What happens with equation (\ref{2}) in these limits? Does it have any mathematical meaning at all?

If both limits are too difficult to deal with, consider the case:
$$C_{\Lambda,\Lambda_{0}}(x,y) = \sum_{p \in \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{d}}\frac{1}{m^{2}+p^{2}}\bigg{[}K\bigg{(}\frac{p^{2}}{\Lambda_{0}^{2}}\bigg{)}-K\bigg{(}\frac{p^{2}}{\Lambda^{2}}\bigg{)}\bigg{]} \tag{3}\label{3}$$
with $K(x) = e^{-x}$. This is a very standard object in the literature; it requires an infinite number of Grassmann variables to define (\ref{1}), but it is possible to do so. However, what would the flow equation mean? In other words, what does it mean to take derivatives with respect to an countable but infinite number of Grassmann variables? Already in this case, it seems problematic to me.

I am really troubled by this question because I know, for instance, that in the case of fermions one could use a cutoff function $K$ with compact support, in which case even in $\mathbb{T}^{*} = \frac{2\pi}{L}\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ the propagator would reduce to a matrix because the cutoff would take to zero the contributions of large $p$. However, in most applications, one uses a cutoff which is not compactly supported, as in the case of the exponential, specially because it is useful to obtain estimates. But then some underlying objects of the theory, such as the evolution equation, seem not to make any mathematical sense at all. Of course, I am not an expert but I don't see the point of making good estimates if the foundations of the theory, the reasons why one is trying to obtain good bounds, is not well-defined?